# mootools javascript return Array.each() with recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion, mootools

I have a JSON object and what I'm trying to achieve is, that I can search the object for child_objects by id. I am using an `Array.each()` and a function with recursion like the following:

```
1  Template.get_object_attributes_by_id = function(id, template)
2  {
3    var template_obj = JSON.parse(template);
4    console.log(Template.check_for_id_equality(template_obj, id);
5    return Template.check_for_id_equality(template_obj, id);
6  }
7 
8  Template.check_for_id_equality = function(obj, id)
9  {
10   if (obj.attrs.id !== id) {
11     if (obj.children === null || obj.children === undefined) {
12       return;
13     }
14     Array.each(obj.children, function(obj_child) {
15       return Template.check_for_id_equality(obj_child, id);
16     });
17   }
18   else {
19     console.log(obj);
20     return obj;
21   }
22 }
```

The output of line 19 is the correct object after calling `Template.get_object_attributes_by_id(id, template)`, but the output of line 4 is `undefined`.
It seems that `Array.each()` "ignores" the return and just keeps going. So now my question is, how to correctly return the object, so that I will get it in the function `get_object_attributes_by_id()`.

**Update:**

The input (the template) is an JSON object like the following, in which I am searching for the id "placeholder-2" for example. It's just an example, so please do not look for missing brackets or something like this, because the real JSON object that I'm using is clearly valid.

```
{
  "className":"Stage",
  "attrs":{
    "width":1337,
    "height":4711
  },
  "children":[{
    "className":"Layer",
    "id":"placeholder-layer",
    "attrs":{
      "width":1337,
      "height": 4711
    },
    "children":[{
      "className":"Text",
      "id":"placeholder-1",
      "attrs":{
        "fontsize":42,
        "color":"black",
        ...
      }
    },
    {
      "className":"Text",
      "id":"placeholder-2",
      "attrs":{
        "fontsize":37,
        "color":"red",
        ...
      }
    },
    ...
    ]
  }]
}
```

And this would the expected output:

```
{
  "className":"Text",
  "id":"placeholder-2",
  "attrs":{
    "fontsize":37,
    "color":"red",
    ...
  },
}
```

Comment: Did you check MooTools's [Object.subset](http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.6.0/Types/Object#Object:Object-subset)? if that is not what you want could you provide a example of the entry and output you want to achieve?

Comment: @Sergio unfortunately `Object.subset` is not what I need. I've updated the question, with an example input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little bit more investigating and trying, my colleague and I solved the problem ourselves, by using a "for"-loop instead of "Array.each()".

Here's the solution:

```
1  Template.get_object_attributes_by_id = function(id, template)
2  {
3    var template_obj = JSON.parse(template);
4    console.log(Template.check_for_id_equality(template_obj, id);
5    return Template.check_for_id_equality(template_obj, id);
6  }
7 
8  Template.check_for_id_equality = function(obj, id)
9  {
10   if (obj.attrs.id === id) {
11     return obj;
12   }
13   if (obj.children === null || obj.children === undefined) {
14       return false;
15   }
16   for (var i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
17     var ret_val = Template.check_for_id_equality(obj.children[i], id);
18     if (ret_val !== false) {
19       return ret_val;
20     }
21   }
22   return false;
23 }
```